# Restore/Edit BCD from a cloned partition

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, partitioning, bcd

I used GParted to transfer my Windows 8.1 Installation from a 128GB SSD to a 256GB one.  (From Ubuntu-Studio in a third HDD drive)

Then while I had still two windows partitions I did login from each to make sure that it was working properly and didn't had any trouble. Then I formated my former windows hard drive with a BSD system and couldn't ever login into windows again. When I try to boot it appears two options when I try the first it goes to a login screen where it get "stucked" I can see it requesting a password but my keyboard doesn't work or the mouse clicks on the shutdown button (I had to hard shutdown).

I tried a couple of different approaches to solve (which didn't change anything) in the problem:

```
Bootrec  /FixMbr
Bootrec  /RebuildBcd
Bootsect /nt60 /force /all
```

When I got back to Ubuntu-Studio again, I could only the windows partition as read only and the message said something about hibernation/sleep. The files appear to be intact.

The Boot folder have the BCD, BCD.Backup.001,BCD.Backup.002 and BCD.Backup.003. 
I tried to read the log files but they were not understandable when open on gedit.

Message when I try to mount as RW:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/mansueli/Win: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/mansueli/Win"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

NOTE: I don't have the files `hiberfil.sys` / `pagefile.sys`. (Removed because they used too much space for minimal benefits in my system *prior* to this clone/transfer)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to delete, or at least temporarily rename, the hiberfil.sys from the Windows partition to force Windows to do a full reboot. You could boot from repair media if Ubuntu will not let you touch that file. You may need to restart Windows in Safe Mode.

After getting Windows to boot at all, do a Windows disk scan and repair, to make the OS recognize the new partition size.

Comment: I already don't have those files as they are not really necessary on my system. (32GB of RAM)